# BreezeJS - Getting newly created entity ID on the server side in EFContextProvider troubles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, breeze

I'm trying to determine the ID(s) of newly added/inserted records which are saved using BreezeJS. The prupose of this, is to broadcast and notify listening clients of changes, so they can update their views if necessary.

BreezeJS provides a useful method to intercept calls to its underlying Data/ObjectContext by way of subclassing a typed EFContextProvider. The parent exposes several methods to override, such as the overridden example below. This works fine for both update/delete operations. However, because this occurs BEFORE saving changes, and thus, no ID has been generated for inserts at this point. I wasn't able to find any other method I could override in this class. At worst, I'll extend the partial datacontext (the ), but I feel this is inelegant to separate this notification system over multiple classes.  Suggestions?

```
 protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo) {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AppHub>();
        if (entityInfo.EntityState == EntityState.Modified) {
            try {
                hubContext.Clients.All.handleEntityUpdate(new {
                    EntityType = entityInfo.Entity.GetType().Name,
                    Key = ((dynamic)(entityInfo.Entity)).Id
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ep) {
                //failed to notifiy the clients. *Oh well* no biggie.
                //Try, catch, curley, curley, curley.
            }
        }
        else if (entityInfo.EntityState == EntityState.Deleted) {
            try {
                hubContext.Clients.All.handleEntityDelete(new {
                    EntityType = entityInfo.Entity.GetType().Name,
                    Key = ((dynamic)(entityInfo.Entity)).Id
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ep) {
                //failed to notifiy the clients. *Oh well* no biggie.
                //Try, catch, curley, curley, curley.
            }
        }

        return base.BeforeSaveEntity(entityInfo);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is poorly documented on the Breeze web site right now but... I'll try to provide some at least minimal help here.  Better docs on this topic are planned... real soon now :)

### Server side

Breeze provides you with the ability to customize KeyGeneration on the server via the implementation of the IKeyGenerator interface ( you can find the interface defined in the Breeze.WebApi  source along with a "fallback" NumericKeyGenerator implementation).

Any custom implementation of this interface in the same assembly as your EFContextProvider will be automatically discovered by Breeze.  Only a single implementation is supported, but a single implementation can be written to support all of the possible datatypes and properties for which you want custom key generation. If Breeze does not find one it will default to the "NumericKeyGenerator" mentioned above.

### Client side

You will then need to create a client side "temporary" key generator.  There is some discussion of this topic on the following page: [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities).

The idea is that Breeze will generate temporary keys for any newly created entities (of specified types) using this "temporary" key generator. When these entities are saved, Breeze will generate a "real" key, using the server side mechanism described above and will save these. Breeze will then return a mapping of the temp -> real keys back to the client and will use this mapping to automatically update the client side entities with the correct "real" keys.

You tell the Breeze client that you want to invoke custom Key generation via the *EntityType.setProperties* method, something like this:

```
var regionType = testFns.metadataStore.getEntityType("Region");
regionType.setProperties({ 
   autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.KeyGenerator }
);
```

Note that you are simply telling Breeze to use a custom key generator.  The server itself will decide which key generator to use based on the logic described above.

By default the "autoGeneratedKeyType" for any EntityType will be either "None" or "Identity", so you will need to set this for any types where you want "custom" key generation.

Once you have this set up, calling EntityManager.saveChanges will automatically invoke key generation on the server and will save your newly added entities with "real" keys and will update the client with these new keys.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My appologies for not awarding you the answer for so long. Thanks Jay!